# HtmlWebpackPlugin - ERROR in Error: The loader "[...]/html-webpack-plugin - /lib/loader.js!/[...]/src/index.html" didn't return html

Tags: javascript, webpack, build

I'm trying to load an HTML template using `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and it seems not working. If I try to load the plugin without arguments it works. Any ideas?

The index.html file that I'm trying to load is in the right place, just to consider

`package.json:`

```
{
 ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
    "@storybook/html": "^5.2.8",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0"
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js:`

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /.(ts|tsx)?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
        exclude: [/node_modules/]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css'
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.scss', '.css']
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [html-webpack-plugin documentation](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md#1-dont-set-any-loader)

> **Don't set any loader**
>
> By default (if you don't specify any loader in any way) a fallback
>   lodash loader kicks in.
>
> ```
> {
>   plugins: [
>     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
>       template: 'src/index.html'
>     })
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> Be aware, using `.html` as your template extention may unexpectedly
>   trigger another loader.

please follow the documentation first and see whether you have any loader conflicts.

Comment: I am getting this error. I do not have loader conflicts. I have not set any loader for `.html` files.

Answer (score 28):

For me, the solution was to make sure everything was updated.

I'm on Webpack 5, and everything except `html-webpack-plugin` was up to date. I updated `html-webpack-plugin` from v4 to v5, and the issue went away.

Comment: I'd like you to know that you answered a year old question and a mere 7 hours later it solved my problem. :)

Comment: omg same, strangeeeeee. It must be due to a recent breaking change in webpack, although I don't remember upgrading it...

Comment: This is really strange!! I faced this issue out of no where and stuck on our prod build and finally could resolve it with upgrading the latest version!

Comment: I actually got this error when upgrading to v5 trying to solve another issue.

Comment: Upgrading to version 5 of the html-webpack-plugin worked!